# Missing electron argument

Tags: javascript, electron, command-line-arguments, electron-packager

I have an electron app that, when packaged, will remove the first argument after the executable name.

For example, the command `launcher.exe a b c` populates `process.argv` from *main.js* and `require('electron').remote.process.argv` from the console with:

```js
[
    "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\launcher\app-0.0.7\launcher.exe",
    "b",
    "c"
]
```

**Where did `a` go? Why? How do I get it back? And why does this only happen once the app is packaged?**

Edit: This problem occurs when I run launcher from "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\launcher\launcher.exe", but not when I run it from "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\launcher\app-0.0.7\launcher.exe". Perhaps this has to do with the electron updater.